# Authorize.net SIM Error 99 - Fingerprint doesn't match

Tags: php, authorize.net, fingerprint

After long days testing and retesting and contacting original programmer, I cannot get this to work.
The software is throwing an ERROR 99. Here is their test page for that error.
http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCode99.html

The software is written in php.

I CHANGED THE KEYS & DATA in this sample code in the program.

```
$transkey = 'abcdefgh12345678';
$fingerprintInput = 'authnettest^789^67897654^10.50^';
$x_fp_hash       = @hash('md5',$fingerprintInput,$transkey);
$x_fp_hash       = @bin2hex($x_fp_hash);
```

The program returns
5958e9cd1cbda15e76a03a82cd11797d

The Authorize.net test page returns
AC7394DC877E29D420D70C24D36E9937

Can someone explain what is going on and what might be done to fix this?

Comment: Are you are sure you are using the right transaction key?

Comment: The key doesn't matter here. This is only a test to compare with their software - see the link I provided to their test page. The test vars, above, were used to get the fingerprint on our side. This was compared with their resulting fingerprint at their test page.

Comment: The fingerprint is generated using that key. If it's not right on your end the fingerprints won't match

Comment: Again, the key does not matter. This is a test page. I am not logged into anet's account, so there is no comparision with what I enter into their test page. It is to ensure the fingerprint is the same on their end as on ours. Even when I try valid data WITH THE CORRECT KEY, it does not work. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but you may want to try the code like as follows as I had the same issue, the authorize.net tool did not have the same comparison hash.

```
$transkey = 'abcdefgh12345678';
$fingerprintInput = 'authnetlogin^789^67897654^10.50^';
$x_fp_hash = hash_hmac("md5", $fingerprintInput, $transkey);
```